# How to download a play-on-click audio file in Python

Tags: javascript, python, audio, web-scraping, pycharm

I'm trying to download foreign-language recordings en masse for a list of words I have. I've been using the source code from [en.bab.la](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/swedish-english/) to find the definitions automatically, and ideally I would like to extract the audio from the same source. A quick look at the source code for [any word](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/swedish-english/gard) shows that (assuming I've understood it right) there isn't just a "download this" button that sends you to a link for the audio file, which is much easier and what I had been using for other websites.

On the actual site for any word, under "Translations & Examples" there's a little audio button; when I hover over it, it says `javascript:babSpeakIt('swedish',52579,'gard');` and so that's what I searched for in the source code, and even though that gets a blue underline like it's a link, it doesn't lead anywhere.

Essentially, this is my question: how can I use python to download that audio that plays on click?

Thank you!

P.S. - I'm using Python 3.6 in Pycharm community edition on Ubuntu 16.04:)

Comment: The JS jumps through few layers before it actually calls the script that "speaks". Another way is to capture audio being spoken.  Here is a article that talks about it. http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-capture-save-record-or-download-streaming-audio-for-free/

Answer (score 0):

You have to examine javascript code that is being called on click event. See what it does and how. You have to find out how do it passes the audio data to the browser.

Then you have to replicate that behaviour in Python. I.e. you must make the right call to the right URL. Or more of them. Then get the data.